# Jest/Enzyme ShallowWrapper is empty when creating Snapshot

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme, snapshot

So I'm writing a test for my Item component and I tried to render the `ItemCard` component and then use that wrapper to create a snapshot but it returns an empty `ShallowWrapper {}`

Please see the code for more info:

Item.test.js

```
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import { ItemCard } from '../Item';

const fakeItem = {
  id: 'aksnfj23',
  title: 'Fake Coat',
  price: '40000',
  description: 'This is suuuper fake...',
  image: 'fakecoat.jpg',
  largeImage: 'largefakecoat.jpg',
};

describe('<ItemCard/>', () => {
  it('renders and matches the snapshot', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<ItemCard me item={fakeItem} showButtons />);

    // console.log(wrapper.debug());
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

The snap it creates:

```
// Jest Snapshot v1

exports[`<ItemCard/> renders and matches the snapshot 1`] = `ShallowWrapper {}`;
```

As far as I know the ShallowWrapper should have some content in it instead of being empty...

Comment: It looks like `mount` instead of `shallow` will make you  happy

Comment: @Alex No. This is not related to mount/shallow.

Comment: @Alez I changed to `mount` from `shallow` in the test to function component and it passed, I don't know why.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I faced the same issue after updating to jest@24.0.0
I have reverted to the previous version jest@23.6.0 for the time being till i figure out what has changed. If you find what has changed, do post it here.

Comment: That's it... I just fixed it yesterday by downgrading Jest.. it's weird but now it works fine.

Comment: downgraded and still facing same issue

Comment: Reverting to `Jest 23` complete breaks Babel if you're on version 7 because it tries to call version 6.

Comment: See the answer by Titenis and the linked GitHub issue.

Answer (score 36):

For jest v24 you need to use snapshot serializer like https://github.com/adriantoine/enzyme-to-json

source: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/7802

Comment: This is not working for me with `jest: 24`, `enzyme: 3.9.0`, `enzyme-adapter-react-16: 1.11.2`, `enzyme-to-json: 3.3.5`. I've installed and configured `enzyme-to-json` in `package.json` but still getting an empty `ShallowWrapper` in the snapshot code. :( The only thing that works is using trusty old `react-test-renderer`, which is not ideal.

Comment: Can confirm working with `jest: 24.1.0`, `enzyme: 3.4.0`, `enzyme-adapter-react-16: 1.2.0`, `enzyme-to-json: 3.4.0`. Should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 26):

There shouldn't be a need of reverting version. Following the official [DOC](https://www.npmjs.com/package/enzyme-to-json#usage)

You need to add this to your [Jest configuration](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html):

```
"snapshotSerializers": ["enzyme-to-json/serializer"]
```

clue:
could be as easy as add it to your **package.json**, like:

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "jest": {
    "snapshotSerializers": ["enzyme-to-json/serializer"]
  }
}
```

Sorry if it wasn't the answer. I just saw no-one told it here and it must help other losts like me few minutes ago.

Comment: You can set the same `snapshotSerializers: ['enzyme-to-json/serializer'],` in jest.config.js

Comment: This still works in Jest v26.  You have to `npm install enzyme-to-json --save-dev` (or `yarn add`), and then either of the above works.

Comment: It the docs it says it has a default serializer but with the solution mentioned here I get my tests passed.

Answer (score 8):

You need to use `jest-enzyme` like:

https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/1533#issuecomment-479591007

Comment: 1. Add dependency `jest-enzyme`
2. Import it in `setupTests.js`

Answer (score 4):

You can just use mount and debug function like this :

```
it('Should render Component', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<Component {...props} />);
    expect(wrapper.debug()).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
```

Comment: work also with Shallow, but just contain inner component

Comment: did you find any solution to this? I am facing same problem, it only has innerComponent without any html in it.

Answer (score 4):

use debug() method after the wrapper

```
  it('renders and matches the snapshot', () => {
const wrapper = shallow(<ItemCard me item={fakeItem} showButtons />);

// console.log(wrapper.debug());
expect(wrapper.debug()).toMatchSnapshot(); });
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue and resolved using serializer https://github.com/adriantoine/enzyme-to-json.

npm install --save-dev enzyme-to-json

Once installed the enzyme-to-json we can use something like below

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {shallow} from 'enzyme';
import toJson from 'enzyme-to-json';

it('renders correctly', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(
    <MyComponent className="my-component">
      <strong>Hello World!</strong>
    </MyComponent>,
  );

  expect(toJson(wrapper)).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

The same can be resolved using `shallow().debug()` but prefer to use the above method.

Comment: also add below in jest configurations:

"snapshotSerializers": ["enzyme-to-json/serializer"]

It may be in 'package.json' file within "jest" object or in 'jest.config.js' file.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a bit late, but i managed to get a solution of this problem by using https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/getElement.html

```
describe("Button", () => {
  it("should render basic button correctly", () => {
    const tree = shallow(<Button></Button>);
    expect(tree.getElement()).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

this work on `Jest 26.5.3` and `enzyme 3.10.5`

Answer (score 0):

just sharing my case:

before I was getting it:

exports[`<ItemCard/> renders and matches the snapshot 1`] = `ShallowWrapper {}`;

I changed 2 places to have everything working as expected:

1. yarn add enzyme-to-json
2. added this line to JEST config in package.json:

`"snapshotSerializers": ["enzyme-to-json/serializer"]`

This is my package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "next": "11.0.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.14.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "7.14.5",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.23",
    "@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17": "^0.6.2",
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-jest": "^27.0.2",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.6.2",
    "eslint": "7.29.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "11.0.0",
    "jest": "^27.0.4"
  },
  "jest": {
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "<rootDir>/setupTests.js"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
      "\\.(css|less)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js"
    },
    "snapshotSerializers": [
      "enzyme-to-json/serializer"
    ]
  }
```