# Jest snapshots return the same code for every tested file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Im running jest enzyme tests, with snapshots. The snapshot files are generated correctly, however their content is basically:

```
// Jest Snapshot v1, https;//link
exports[`Component1 should match snapshot 1`] = `ReactWrapper {}`;
         ^^^^^^^^ <-- only component name is changing
```

for every tested file, even if tested files have complicated logic and 400+ lines of code.

Why does it happen? Where's the whole code?

```
it('should match snapshot', () => {
  const component = mount(<Component1 />);

  expect(component).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Comment: Please add the code where you render the component for test.

Comment: @jmargolisvt Added

Comment: Try using `shallow` instead of `mount`.

Comment: @jmargolisvt nothing changed except for `ReactWrapper` into `ShallowWrapper`

Comment: This seems related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54419342/jest-enzyme-shallowwrapper-is-empty-when-creating-snapshot I'm looking at my own tests and it seems the enzyme-to-json package is needed to create useful snapshots with Jest.

Comment: @jmargolisvt Please post full answer with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm looking at my own tests and it seems the `enzyme-to-json` package is needed to create useful snapshots with Jest.  This will serialize your data for use with Jest.