# How to snapshot test a component with nested component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jackson, jestjs

I'm testing a component with a nested component inside which use redux. I'm using shallow test for the component.
This is my test:

```
describe("Header", () =>
  void it("renders correctly", () => {
    const renderer = new ShallowRenderer()
    const tree = renderer.render(<Header />)
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  })
```

The snapshot output is:

```
exports[`Header renders correctly 1`] = `
<mockConstructor
  render={[Function]}
/>
`;
```

Is this correct? Shouldn't a snapshot show my component?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `shallow` from the `enzyme` package:

```
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Header from './Header';

describe('Header', () => {
  it('should render', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Header />);
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed my code as you say and the snapshot output for your snippet is:

```
exports[`Header renders correctly 1`] = `ShallowWrapper {}`;
```

Looking information about this output i found [Jest/Enzyme ShallowWrapper is empty when creating Snapshot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54419342/jest-enzyme-shallowwrapper-is-empty-when-creating-snapshot)
Basically i have to use enzyme-to-json, so i changed my code to:

```
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import toJson from 'enzyme-to-json';
...

describe("Header", () =>
  void it("renders correctly", () => {
    const tree = shallow(<Header />)
    expect(toJson(tree)).toMatchSnapshot()
  })
)
```

In the github site for `enzyme-to-json` there is a example that show as my test

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {shallow} from 'enzyme';
import toJson from 'enzyme-to-json';

it('renders correctly', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(
    <MyComponent className="my-component">
      <strong>Hello World!</strong>
    </MyComponent>
  );

  expect(toJson(wrapper)).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

But the snapshot is:

```
exports[`Header renders correctly 1`] = `
<mockConstructor
  render={[Function]}
/>
`;
```